# Binding HTML strings in Ember.JS

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, swiftype

I am using a third party indexing service (Swiftype) to search through my database. The returned records contains a property called `highlight`. This simply adds `<em>` tags around matching strings.

I then bind this `highlight` property in Ember.JS Handlebars as such:

```
<p> Title: {{highlight.title}} </p>
```

Which results in the following output:

```
Title: Example <em>matching</em> text
```

The browse actually displays the `<em>` tags, instead of formatting them. I.e. Handlebars is not identifying the HTML tags, and simply printing them as a string.

Is there a way around this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Handlebars by default escapes html, to prevent escaping, use triple brackets:

`<p> Title: {{{highlight.title}}} </p>`

See http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping

Answer (score 0):

Ember escapes html because it could be potentional bad code which can be executed. To avoid that use

```
Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("<em>MyString</em>");
```

Here are the docs
http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/

if you've done that you could use {{hightlight.title}} like wished,...

HTH